# Algorithm / Code to find dependency and build row column wise hierarchy model using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, hierarchy

Suppose I have two columns ColA = Calling programs and ColB = Called programs, now I want to build a hierarchy between calling and called program and print them with the calling dependency lvl column as below.

Note:

1. Calling program for which called program is SPACES, is the initial program for a new branch.
2. Output representation can differ, but it has to be in row and column only.

Input columns:

```
COLA  COLB

AAA
AAA   BBB
AAA   CCC
BBB 
BBB   CCC
CCC   DDD
CCC   GGG
CCC   HHH
DDD
DDD   III
DDD   MMM
EEE
EEE   BBB   
EEE   FFF
EEE   JJJ
EEE   KKK
FFF 
FFF   LLL
FFF   MMM
FFF   NNN
MMM   OOO
```

Output:

```
COLA(Initial)   LVL COLB(Calling)   COLC(Called)
AAA              1
AAA              2   BBB
AAA              3   CCC
AAA              4   DDD
AAA              5   III
AAA              5   MMM
AAA              6   OOO
AAA              4   GGG
AAA              4   HHH
AAA              2   CCC
AAA              3   DDD
AAA              4   III
AAA              4   MMM
AAA              5   OOO
AAA              3   GGG
AAA              3   HHH

BBB              1
BBB              2   CCC
BBB              3   DDD
BBB              4   III
BBB              4   MMM
BBB              5   OOO
BBB              3   GGG
BBB              3   HHH

DDD              1
DDD              2   III
DDD              2   MMM
DDD              3   OOO

EEE              1
EEE              2   FFF
EEE              3   LLL
EEE              3   MMM
EEE              4   OOO
EEE              3   NNN
EEE              2   JJJ
EEE              2   KKK

FFF              1
FFF              2   LLL
FFF              2   MMM
FFF              3   OOO
FFF              2   NNN
```

I tried, but I am stuck at LVL 4 and the recursive loop. Please suggest

```
for i = 1 to i <= last row
   lvl_no = 0
   if CCi == SPACES
      OBJECT_NAME = CAi 
      lvl_no = 1    
      copy row i to new excel
      for j = 1 to j <= last row
     if CAj = OBJECT_NAME && CCj != SPACES
        lvl_no = 1 + 1
        copy row j to new excel
        dep_obj = CCj
        ROW = 1             BBB
        function_dep(dep_obj,lvl_no,ROW)
        j++
    ELSE J++

function_dep (object_name, lvl, row)
{
  for k=row to k<= last_row
     if CAk = object_name && CCk !=spaces
       lvl = lvl + 1
       dep_obj = CCk
       row = 1
       print line k, lvl
       call function_dep(dep_obj, lvl, row)
     else k++   
}
```

As per the below comment suggestion I updated my input with some new rows like (DDD , EEE  BBB and MMM    OOO), and as per the input the output also got updated with new levels as per dependencies.

Below suggested solution no working for me, as for EEE->BBB dependency it is only showing single row EEE->BBB and missed the whole forward dependencies (EEE->BBB->CCC->DDD and so on) considering it as a duplicate.

Comment: The code you show is no VBA code. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Please have a look if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738569/loop-through-a-range-to-create-a-tree-of-nested-data/52741800#52741800

Comment: Well we can only help to fix your issues if you show the code you have tried. Please also check the link I posted. Also according [ask] we need a concrete question to answer.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The above code is just a rough code flow , and not specific to any language.
I tried your code, it's good but there are some issue, as I added one more depency row in last (MMM     OOOO), and the output of this came in end of the table, this can be a issue for me, as if there are thousands of line, then this dependency will be lost as the rows are not in sequence,
also as I mentioned every program for which COLB (called program) is SPACES that is an initial program for every branch, but your code left that because of repetitive dependency and missed the level part.

Comment: Please don't post data or code in comments. Always [edit] your question and just leave a comment for a short explanation what you updated. Please show in your quesiton exactly what you did and what result you got and what you expected. Of course the code in the link is unlikely to do exactly what you want but should give you a good start.